# Cleanest way to iterate through a loop in Ruby, while outputting two values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have a simple loop, which is fed an Array with multiple elements, the goal of my function is to iterate over each element, with the value of ID to be the same as the ID of the element currently in the loop
and the value of 'body' to be that of the entire same element.

I'm struggling to ensure that the loop resets and feeds in a new element every iteration, rather than one or the other remaining in the loop.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

```
@data = [{ 'url' => 'https://zendesk.com/api/v2/macros/1900002708354.json',
           'id' => 1_900_002_708_354,
           'actions' => [{ 'field' => 'comment_value_html', 'value' => '{{email}} 360081752739' }],
           'restriction' => nil },
         { 'url' => 'https://zendesk.com/api/v2/macros/360081752739.json',
           'id' => 360_081_752_739,
           'actions' => [{ 'field' => 'comment_value_html', 'value' => '{{IBAN}} ' }],
           'restriction' => nil },
         { 'url' => 'https://zendesk.com/api/v2/macros/360081755559.json',
           'id' => 360_081_755_559,
           'actions' => [{ 'field' => 'comment_value_html', 'value' => '{{email}} 360081752739' }],
           'restriction' => nil }]





def run_function
  @data.each do |x|
    @id = [x.select { |m| m['id'] }]
    final_data = x
    body = final_data
    puts body
  end
 end
```

My ID variable currently outputs as `[{"id"=>1900002708354}]`, whereas I only require the number.

Comment: For the love of god, please indent the code properly. Otherwise the code becomes impossible to scan.

Comment: In this particular case, the body of the `each` should be indented by one level.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ok. Correct?

Comment: Perfect. Now, I have questions about the code. Not sure what you attempted to do with `@data.select { |m| m['actions'] }.map { |m| m['id'] }`, but it most certainly is not doing what you think it does. It'll have the same value (a list of all ids) at each iteration. In particular, `.select { |m| m['actions'] }` is useless (given the provided input array)

Comment: "I'm struggling to ensure that the loop resets and feeds in a new element every iteration, rather than one or the other remaining in the loop." - I have no idea what you wanted to say here, but `x` is that element (next element at each iteration)

Comment: You're probably overusing instance variables too. I see no reason for, say, `final_data` to be an instance variable instead of local variable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Noted, I've updated with what I have just tried, but as far as I can see, the id still doesn't track with that of the current element.

Comment: of course it doesn't. You access the id of the current element with `x["id"]`

Comment: @cbin1 : Since `@data` is an array of Hashes, `x` must be a Hash. What's the point in applying `select` to a Hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
@data.each do |hash|
  id = hash['id']
  puts id
end
```